# USB tethering (internet sharing) not working with Samsung Galaxy S10e and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, android, samsung, tethering

I try to use my Samsung Galaxy S10e as internet connection with my laptop and Xubuntu 22.04 via USB cable.

I can establish a connection:

```
~$ sudo dmesg
[ 8666.252715] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 8666.407548] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860, bcdDevice= c.00
[ 8666.407558] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8666.407562] usb 1-4: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[ 8666.407564] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[ 8666.407567] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: RF8R20KASDF
```

and get an ip:

```
~$ ifconfig

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.253.109  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.253.255
        inet6 fe80::5973:a630:b03a:cb2f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ea:38:73:9a:5f:df  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 229  bytes 60459 (60.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 330  bytes 189389 (189.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and ping an internet address:

```
~$ ping tv2.dk
PING tv2.dk (199.232.42.217) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 199.232.42.217 (199.232.42.217): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=16.3 ms
64 bytes from 199.232.42.217 (199.232.42.217): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=34.3 ms
```

But browsing is not working properly. Only small parts of pages are loaded, if any.

Here's an example with wget:

```
~$ wget -O slet -d https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/spai/q_lossy+w_998+to_avif+ret_img/https://www.mindful.org/content/uploads/What-Happens-When-We-Reconnect-with-Nature.jpg
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.21.2 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/tj/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2022-06-03 22:46:46--  https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/spai/q_lossy+w_998+to_avif+ret_img/https://www.mindful.org/content/uploads/What-Happens-When-We-Reconnect-with-Nature.jpg
Løser cdn.shortpixel.ai (cdn.shortpixel.ai)... 194.242.11.186
Caching cdn.shortpixel.ai => 194.242.11.186
Tilslutter cdn.shortpixel.ai (cdn.shortpixel.ai)|194.242.11.186|:443... forbundet.
Created socket 4.
Releasing 0x00005616f3cfc970 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 4 to SSL handle 0x00005616f3cfd650
certificate:
  subject: CN=*.shortpixel.ai
  issuer:  CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA,O=Sectigo Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host cdn.shortpixel.ai

---request begin---
GET /spai/q_lossy+w_998+to_avif+ret_img/https://www.mindful.org/content/uploads/What-Happens-When-We-Reconnect-with-Nature.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: cdn.shortpixel.ai
User-Agent: Wget/1.21.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP forespørgsel sendt, afventer svar... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 03 Jun 2022 20:46:46 GMT
Content-Type: image/avif
Content-Length: 92431
Connection: keep-alive
Server: BunnyCDN-NO1-830
CDN-PullZone: 257218
CDN-Uid: ceac3dab-9909-4315-8d54-a27751b54dd0
CDN-RequestCountryCode: DK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Server, x-goog-meta-frames, Content-Length, Content-Type, Range, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Server, x-goog-meta-frames, Content-Length, Content-Type, Range, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match
Cache-Control: max-age=30303404, s-maxage=604800
ETag: 4b11220eed5fe18fa2b5054aced4331d
Expires: Sat, 20 May 2023 04:45:30 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 20 May 2022 05:45:30 GMT
Pragma: cache
CDN-CachedAt: 06/03/2022 20:45:42
Link: <https://www.mindful.org/content/uploads/What-Happens-When-We-Reconnect-with-Nature.jpg>; rel="canonical"
CDN-Tag: 2299945; Domain: www.mindful.org; 200
XTag-SP-Debug: SLT: 0.012
CDN-ProxyVer: 1.02
CDN-RequestPullCode: 200
CDN-RequestPullSuccess: True
CDN-EdgeStorageId: 830
CDN-Status: 200
CDN-RequestId: 60f1fd865a714e93b083b4b328afbafb
CDN-Cache: HIT

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 4 for persistent reuse.
Længde: 92431 (90K) [image/avif]
Gemmer til: ‘slet’

slet                                               17%[==================>   ...   ]  16,00K  --.-KB/s    eta 1m 46s ^C
```

Download stops at 16KB.

I have an older Samsung Galaxy A3 which is working fine in the same setup (same pc, cable, SIM card/carrier).

Any suggestions? Is the problem Ubuntu or the phone?

Comment: Have you tried with another computer? Have you tried with the Ubuntu live USB?

Comment: The problem is your WiFi MTU. It's 1500, should be 1492 for WiFi. Read `man ip-link ip sudo` to see how to set your MTU. You're suffering from "packet fragmention", which doubles the number of packets sent.

Comment: @user68186 I have the same problem with another computer with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @waltinator This is not WiFi but USB cable. Is your comment still relevant?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have the same problem w/ 20.04 & s10e.  Did you manage to get a resolution?

Comment: No, I bought a Sony Experia 10 III - it works perfect with both USB, battery charge threshold, etc. :-)